# How to redirect URl in ISS url rewrite module?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I want to redirect from url http://localhost/article.aspx?id=342&title=article to http://localhost/article.aspx?id=12&title=articleusing IIS.

I tried by placing direct url in by adding rule. but its not working

Comment: Beginners should learn and avoid common mistakes, https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0):

Could you try below rule:

```
 <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="article.aspx" />
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=342&amp;title=article" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost/article.aspx?id=12&amp;title=article" />
                </rule>
```